# Using jqtransform plugin on all but one form

Tags: javascript, css, forms, jqtransform

We're using the jQuery jqtransform plugin to style our site's forms. There's one form though that we don't want it to change. I modified the script that runs jqtransform on all forms to the following:

```
 $('form:not(.classOfFormWeDon'tWantToChange)').jqTransform();
```

It still has the same effect as running it on all forms though. Is something wrong with the way the :not selector is being used? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This should work.

```
$('form').not('.classOfFormWeDontWantToChange').jqTransform();
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/EtbSr/1/) for illustration of this type of syntax.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I actually tried that already, just did it again but still nothing. Any other thoughts?

Comment: If you create a fiddle I can give it a shot. Could be something small.

Comment: I couldn't get it to work with a fiddle, possibly because they didn't have the exact jQuery version we're using. Here is a live example though. Drop down using jqtransform is here: http://veniceislandhouse.com/HelixMix/Products.aspx And the other form that we don't want it to change is here: http://veniceislandhouse.com/HelixMix/WhereToBuy.aspx

Comment: It's currently using: $('form').not('.mapsAC').jqTransform(); which seems to be modifying all forms, even though it's told not to if they have a class of mapsAC.

Comment: If you remove the line of code that runs jqtransform on form tags then the drop down breaks of course and the form on the other page goes back to looking correct.

Comment: Hmm i see an error in the console that jquery 2.0.3 min is not found. Maybe you should try with older(stable) version of jquery.

Comment: Well jqtransform is using an older version, which is included. 2.0.3 is also included, and it seems that it can find it since when you view the source it is there... But that version can be removed completely and jqtransform will still work.

Comment: Well, i'm running out of ideas, but it might be possible that jqtransofrm doesn't get along with .not()